# OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device. where to locate chromedrivermanager on Mac?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm working on automation of some activities on a website using Selenium on Jupiter notebook. After running this line of code

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```

so many times, I got this error `OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device.`
I assume this is due to me keep installing chrome driver manager too many times, taking much of space on my Mac.
but I cannot find where it is installed.

I tried to go through basically every files under this path    `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9` (I got this path when enter command `which python3` in terminal) but still no results.

any ideas or any commands that help to locate `chromedrivermanager`? thank you so much.

Comment: chromedriver will install in its own folder. Look for it in the same location you would look for new installed programs. It shouldn't install anywhere inside python folders.

Comment: The path you have is the location of your python executable.

Comment: Thanks Jesse, but I don't know where I normally install new programs, never pay attention to the paths. where do you install your programs? maybe my path is similar to yours?

Comment: Try something like /usr/local/YOUR_USER_NAME

Answer (score 0):

You can get the location of the downloaded driver as follows:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

print(Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()).path)
```